# Need to retrieve rows from table where the following condition was not satisfied column A = column B and column B = column A

Tags: sql, join, notin

I hope I am able to explain what I am looking for. I have a table as follows:

```
ID | Column A| Column B
1  | 1234    | 9876    
2  | 1234    | 8765    
3  | 9876    | 1234    
4  | 2345    | 3456    
5  | 3456    | 2345
```

The rule is that For Every value of Column A = Value A and Column B = Value B, I need to have a row where Column A = Value B and Column B = Value A.

Here, I have ID = 1, 3, 4 and 5 satisfying this condition.

I need to pull ID = 2 as this was not satisfying the rule.

Will this query work for the above condition:

```
select * from TABLE1 T1 where T1.ID not in (select ID from TABLE1 
where T1.Column A = Column B and T1.Column B = Column A)
```

Is there a better way to write this query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 T1 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TABLE1 T2 
                  WHERE T1.ColumnA = T2.ColumnB AND 
                        T1.ColumnB = T2.ColumnA)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This query works for the requirement I had.

Answer (score 0):

Use an outer self-join filtering out matches:

```
select a.*
from table1 a
left join table1 b on a.columna = b.columnb
  and a.columnb = b.columna
where b.columnb is null
```

Comment: But I always have data in Column B. It is never a NULL value.

Comment: @user3430457 This query should work. After the `JOIN`, `b.ColumnA` and `b.ColumnB` will be NULL in cases where there wasn't a match.

Comment: @siddy this doesn't select rows where columnb is null! It picks rows *from the join* where it's null, which happens when there is no join - ie this picks all rows that *don't* have a matching joined row, which is exactly what you want. Try the query and see for yourself. Also, this query will out-perform a "where not in" type query

Answer (score -1):

```
select
    a.*
from
   Table1 a
join
   Table1 b on
        a.ColumnA = b.ColumnB and
        a.ColumnB = b.ColumnA
```